# How can I set a timer function through a connection handler?

Tags: kdb

I'm having problems setting a .z.ts timer through my connection handler:

```
q)h "0N!.z.T"
09:49:55.524
q)h ".z.ts: {0N!x}"
q)h "\t 1000"
1000
q)
```

*nothing displayed...*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting t as follows:

```
h"system \"t 1000\""
```

[This](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/system) explains the difference between system and \ .

Comment: I still don't see any output from the server.

Comment: You will see output ON the server, but not in the calling client. You are setting the function remotely, so you should not expect an output in the client.

Comment: ok, but I'm not clear why the timer output device would be different than the one used by a call to `h ".z.T"`.

Comment: 0N!  will print result on the server and return .z.T to the client.  That's why you see it in your first example

Comment: `h(system;"t 1000")` is slightly nicer because we can avoid escaping the quotes.